# loadForm change behaviour from J!3.9 to J!4.0 and data not loaded with the form

Tags: extensions, form, joomla-4.x, kunena

In my component in a model backend, I'm loading a form but since moving the code to be used on J!4.0 the data associated to the form isn't loaded anymore.

The loadForm is called: https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/blob/K6.0/src/admin/src/Model/TemplateModel.php#L55

The form is being loaded, but it doesn't load the data with the form.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, i just found it. The method loadFormData() in model was removed by mistake